# Why is the order of the special characters on the keyboard like !@#$%^&*()?

Tags: history

The order wasn't easy for me to memorize. I would like to know if there is a historical story.

Comment: The order is different on keyboards from different countries.  Also, the order would come from typewriters, pre-dating computer keyboards.  Or are you asking why the order in ASCII is the way it is?

Comment: A related question: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9127/why-are-the-symbols-on-the-number-keys-of-pc-mac-keyboards-different-to-ascii

Comment: If it is !"#$%&'() then it would be ASCII.  You'll get used to it until you change countries or from a desktop to a laptop.  Then things start going weird.  It is particularly difficult if you program in python or C derived languages.